# Do the maximal intervals of an ODE solution vary continuously?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider the following Cauchy problem (which we will denote by IVP$_{x_0}$ )
$$\dot {x} = F (x)$$
$$x(0) = x_0,$$
where $F:U \subset \mathbb {R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^n $ is a $\mathcal {C}^{\infty}$ function, and $U $ is an open set.

Let $\varphi (t,x)$ be the flow of the above differential equation, *i. e.* $\varphi $ satisfies the conditions:

- $\frac {d \varphi }{dt}(t,x) = F (\varphi (t,x))$.
- $\varphi (0,x) = x$, $\forall$ $x $ $\in$ $U $.
- $\varphi (t,x) $ is the maximal solution of the IVP$_{x}$.

For each $y$ $\in$ $U$ fixed, we can associate this value to an open interval $\left(- \omega_{y}^ {(1)}, \omega_{y}^{(2)}\right)$ corresponding to the domain of the maximal solution of the IVP$_y$, *i. e,* $\left(- \omega^{(1)}_{y}, \omega_{y}^{(2 )}\right)$ is the domain of $g (t) = \varphi (t,y).$

Now, I would like to know if

\begin{align*}\Psi : U &\rightarrow \mathbb {R} \\
x &\mapsto \min \left\{\omega_{x}^{(1)} , \omega_{x}^{(2)},1\right\}
\end{align*}
is a continuous function. Does anyone know how I prove this?

**EDIT:** I found an easy counter-example:

Define $U := \left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)\times \left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right) \setminus \{0,0\}$. Consider the function

\begin{align*}F: U& \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\\
 u& \mapsto  (1,0),
\end{align*}

then trivially $\Psi$ is not continuous, this example is particularly interesting because $F$ has no singular points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not continuous.

Simplest example: in the line consider $F$ with a single zero such that all other solutions nonglobal. Say $F(x)=x^2$.

The best that you can say is that $$\left\{\left(x,\omega_x^{(1)},\omega_x^{(2)}\right):x\in\mathbb R^n\right\}$$ is an open set (see for example Hale's ODE book).

Comment: It's true, I forgot to say that the field has no singular points, I will edit the question

Comment: I have already replied, in a complete manner, it is quite inappropriate to change the question. Please avoiding doing this!

Comment: I know, I'm sorry

Comment: I returned the question to the original version, I thought it would not be fair if you did not receive the credits for your answer. Do you think I should create a new post with the question formulated correctly, or rather forget about it?

Comment: You certainly should never forget about a question! We all like to learn.